# When does $\int_a^\infty g(x)/f(x)\,dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration

> When does $\int_a^\infty g(x)/f(x) \,dx$ converge?

Where $g$ and $f$ are polynomials.

I am not so sure about this pattern. Consider,

$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^3 + x^2 + x + 1} \, dx$, this integral converges, but $\int_1^\infty \frac{4x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x + 1} \,dx$ does not converge.

How can I tell when it converges? And what is the pattern?

Comment: In your example, the first integrand is $\approx 1/x^3$ for large $x,$ the second one is $\approx 1/x.$ Integrate those simpler functions on $[a,\infty)$ to see what's happening.

Comment: Are you given any conditions on $a$? Is $a > 0$, for example?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For any exponent $r$, you know when $\int_1^\infty x^r \,dx$ converges.

> It converges iff $r < -1$.

So in the general case, compare with this integral.

Answer (score 0):

In the integral $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{4x^2}{x^3 + x^2 + x + 1} \,dx$ the leading terms in the numerator and denominator are $4x^2$ and $x^3$, so as $x\to\infty$ it goes to $0$ at a rate comparable to that  of $4x^2/x^3 = 4/x$, so the integral diverges.

$$
\frac{4x^2}{x^3+x^2+x+1} = \frac 4 {x + 1 + \dfrac 1 x + \dfrac 1 {x^2}} \ge  \frac 1 x \text{ if } x\ge 1, \text{ and } \int_1^\infty \frac{dx} x = \infty.
$$

By contrast $\dfrac 1 {x^3+x^2+x+1} \le \dfrac 1 {x^2}$ and $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x^2}<\infty.$